# Why header "linux/if_ppp.h" returns errors?

Tags: c++, c, linux, interface, ppp

I would like to implement the solution of user @bunto1 from this post ([What is the easiest way to get PPP0 interface Tx/Rx bytes in a custom C/C++ program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54163647/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-ppp0-interface-tx-rx-bytes-in-a-custom-c-c-prog)) in my code:

It consists in reading RX and TX from the "ppp0" interface.

```
    #include <linux/if_ppp.h>
    #include <net/if.h>
    #include <sys/ioctl.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
```

Code:

```
    auto sockfd = ::socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (sockfd < 0) {
        std::cout << "couldn't open socket : " << errno << std::endl;
        return;
    }

    ifreq req {};
    ppp_stats stats {};

    req.ifr_data = reinterpret_cast<caddr_t>(&stats);
    ::strncpy(&req.ifr_name[0], "ppp0", sizeof(req.ifr_name));

    auto ret = ::ioctl(sockfd, SIOCGPPPSTATS, &req);
    if (ret < 0) {
        std::cout << "couldn't get PPP statistics : " << errno << std::endl;
    } else {
        std::cout << "received bytes : " << stats.p.ppp_ibytes << std::endl;
        std::cout << "sent bytes : " << stats.p.ppp_obytes << std::endl;
    }

    auto ret = ::close(sockfd);
    if (ret != 0) {
        std::cout << "couldn't close socket : " << errno << std::endl;
    }
```

Unfortunately, when I wrote this code for myself, the compiler reports an error:

```
/usr/include/linux/if_ppp.h:92:7: error: use of enum ‘NPmode’ without previous declaration
  enum NPmode mode;
       ^
/usr/include/linux/if_ppp.h:103:16: error: field ‘b’ has incomplete type ‘ifreq’
  struct ifreq  b;
                ^
/usr/include/linux/if_ppp.h:104:19: error: field ‘stats’ has incomplete type ‘ppp_stats’
  struct ppp_stats stats;   /* statistic information */
                   ^
/usr/include/linux/if_ppp.h:108:21: error: field ‘b’ has incomplete type ‘ifreq’
  struct ifreq       b;
                     ^
usr/include/linux/if_ppp.h:109:24: error: field ‘stats’ has incomplete type ‘ppp_comp_stats’
  struct ppp_comp_stats stats;
```

I noticed that this is due to the inclusion of a header file:

```
#include <linux/if_ppp.h>
```

What could this be caused by?

Comment: You probably need to include `linux/ppp_defs.h` before `linux/if_ppp.h` .

Comment: @M.G.  It did not solve the problem

Comment: Works fine on my system  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ maybe your header files are corrupted?

Comment: Likewise on my own system.  Can't repro.

Comment: What is your version of the package? I have this header in "pppd-2.4.7"

Comment: @Creatorek On my ubuntu system, the header is from the package linux-libc-dev and my version is 5.4.0-73.82

Comment: It might work if you also use the `linux/ppp_defs.h` from "pppd-2.4.7", but you should probably use the official Linux headers rather than pppd's internal, 19-year-old versions.